# Using Selenium Webdriver TakesScreenshot method to capture a base64 image. Can I reduce the image size?

Tags: java, image, selenium, base64, screenshot

I am using Selenium's TakesScreenshot method getting a base64 string into my HTML report. The screenshot produced in the report (extentreports) is a little too big, and is partially pushed offscreen. Shrinking it would also reduce the report's file size.

Can I take a smaller base64 screenshot? Shrinking it by about 20% would be perfect... Or would I have to create the image as a `File` first, then shrink it, then convert to base64.

```
 public static String CaptureScreen(WebDriver driver) {
    TakesScreenshot newScreen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    String scnShot = newScreen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
    return "data:image/jpg;base64, " + scnShot ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a smaller screenshot file. You should be reduced image quality or write file with a fixed dimension (height x width). Let check my solution hope this help:

LIB:

```
<!-- SELENIUM LIBs and Image Process LIBs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

1. Solution: First using reduce image quality, I defined

   - maximum image size is: ex: 1048576

   Take a screenshot to a file (you choose is a base64 is up to you)

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics2D;
   import java.awt.RenderingHints;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
   import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
   import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
   import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.util.Hashtable;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
   import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
   import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;

   /**

   - @author daviddoan
     *
     */
     public class ScreenShotUtils implements ImageObserver {

     private static final Color BKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
     private boolean imageLoaded = false;

     private static BufferedImage matrixTransparentPixels(BufferedImage originalBufferedImage, Color fillColor) {
     int w = originalBufferedImage.getWidth();
     int h = originalBufferedImage.getHeight();
     BufferedImage newGeneratedBufferedImage;
     if (originalBufferedImage.getType() == BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) {
       newGeneratedBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
     } else {
       newGeneratedBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, originalBufferedImage.getType());
     }
     // clone the original image
     Graphics2D graphics2D = null;
     try {
       graphics2D = newGeneratedBufferedImage.createGraphics();
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
       final boolean isDrawingSuccess = graphics2D.drawImage(originalBufferedImage, 0, 0, w, h, fillColor, null);
       if (!isDrawingSuccess) {
       while (!imageLoaded) {
         System.err.println("DRAWING IMAGE, PLEASE WAITING...");
         Thread.sleep(10000);
       }
       }
     } finally {
       if (graphics2D != null) {
         graphics2D.dispose();
       }
     }

     return newGeneratedBufferedImage;
     }

     public static void reduceScreenShotQuality(File screenshotSource, String location, String fileName, String fileExtension) throws Exception {

     int sizeThreshold = 1048576;
     float quality = 1.0f;
     long fileSize = screenshotSource.length();

     if (fileSize <= sizeThreshold) {
       // Image file size is small, no need reduced any more.;
       writeImageToLocation(screenshotSource, location, fileName, "jpeg");
       return;
     }

     // Need to reduce 'cos over sizeThreshold

     ImageWriter writer = createImageWriter();

     ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

     iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

     InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(screenshotSource);

     FileImageOutputStream output = getOutputStream(location, fileName, fileExtension);

     BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
     BufferedImage newBufferedImage;

     newBufferedImage = matrixTransparentPixels(originalImage, BKGROUND_COLOR);

     float percent = 0.1f; // 10% of 1

     while (fileSize > sizeThreshold) {
       if (percent >= quality) {
         percent = percent * 0.1f;
       }

     quality -= percent;

     iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);

     writeImage(writer, newBufferedImage, output, iwp);

     File fileOut2 = new File(location + fileName + "." + fileExtension);
       long newFileSize = fileOut2.length();
       if (newFileSize == fileSize) {
         // cannot reduce more
         break;
       } else {
         fileSize = newFileSize;
       }
     }
     // Flush all stream
     inputStream.close();
     originalImage.flush();
     newBufferedImage.flush();
     writer.dispose();
     }

     private static void writeImage(ImageWriter writer, BufferedImage bufferedImage, FileImageOutputStream output, ImageWriteParam iwp) {
     try {
       IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
       writer.setOutput(output);

     if (iwp != null) {
         writer.write(null, image, iwp);
       } else {
         writer.write(image);
       }
       output.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("writeImage: IOException- " + e.getMessage());
     } finally {
       System.err.println("End writeImage");
     }

     }

     private static FileImageOutputStream getOutputStream(String location, String fileName, String fileExtension) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
     File fileOut = new File(location + fileName + "." + fileExtension);
     if (fileOut.exists()) {
       fileOut.delete();
     }
     FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(fileOut);

     return output;
     }

     private static ImageWriter createImageWriter() {
     Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
     ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
     return writer;
     }

     private static void writeImageToLocation(File filePng, String location, String fileName, String extension) throws IOException {
     ImageWriter writer = createImageWriter();

     ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

     SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(filePng);
     PNGDecodeParam pngParams = new PNGDecodeParam();
     ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("png", seekableStream, pngParams);
     RenderedImage pngImage = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage();

     BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(pngImage.getWidth(), pngImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

     newImage.createGraphics().drawImage(renderedImageToBufferedImage(pngImage), 0, 0, Color.BLACK, null);

     FileImageOutputStream output = getOutputStream(location, fileName, extension);
     writeImage(writer, newImage, output, iwp);

     newImage.flush();
     seekableStream.close();
     writer.dispose();
     }

     private static BufferedImage renderedImageToBufferedImage(RenderedImage img) {
     if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
       return (BufferedImage) img;
     }
     ColorModel cm = img.getColorModel();
     int width = img.getWidth();
     int height = img.getHeight();
     WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height);
     boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
     Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
     String[] keys = img.getPropertyNames();
     if (keys != null) {
       for (String key : keys) {
         properties.put(key, img.getProperty(key));
       }
     }
     BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, properties);
     img.copyData(raster);
     return result;
     }
     }
     @Override
     public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
         if (infoflags != ALLBITS) {
             // Image has not finished loading!
             // Return true to tell the image loading thread to keep drawing until image fully loads.
             return true;
         } else {
             imageLoaded = true;
             return false;
         }
     }

     2. Solution: Write as a thumbnail image (heigh x width)

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics2D;
   import java.awt.Image;
   import java.awt.RenderingHints;
   import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import javax.media.jai.JAI;
   import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

   import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;

   /**

   - - @author daviddoan
       *
       */

   public class ThumbnailUtils implements ImageObserver {

   ```
   private static final String CLASS_NAME = ThumbnailUtils.class.getSimpleName();

   private final Color BKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
   private boolean imageLoaded = false;

   public void writeThumbnail(String originalImagePath, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight, String thumbImagePath)
           throws Exception {

       InputStream originalImageStream = new FileInputStream(originalImagePath);
       File fileOut = new File(thumbImagePath);
       if (fileOut.exists()) {
           fileOut.delete();
       }
       OutputStream thumbImageOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
       writeThumbnail(originalImageStream, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, thumbImageOutStream);
       thumbImageOutStream.close();
       originalImageStream.close();
   }

   public void writeThumbnail(File file, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight, String thumbImagePath) throws Exception {

       InputStream originalImageStream = new FileInputStream(file);
       File fileOut = new File(thumbImagePath);
       if (fileOut.exists()) {
           fileOut.delete();
       }
       OutputStream thumbImageOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);

       writeThumbnail(originalImageStream, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, thumbImageOutStream);

       thumbImageOutStream.close();
       originalImageStream.close();

   }

   private void writeThumbnail(InputStream originalImageStream, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight,
           OutputStream thumbImageOutStream) throws Exception {

       ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrOutputStream = null;
       try {
           byteArrOutputStream = makeThumbnail(originalImageStream, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
           byteArrOutputStream.writeTo(thumbImageOutStream);
           byteArrOutputStream.flush();
       } finally {
           if (byteArrOutputStream != null) {
               byteArrOutputStream.close();
           }
       }

   }

   private Image makeThumbnail(final Image originalImage, final int maxWidth, final int maxHeight) throws Exception {
       // ImageOveserve is ingnored for BufferedImages
       final int photoWidth = originalImage.getWidth(null);
       final int photoHeight = originalImage.getHeight(null);

       int thumbWidth = maxWidth;
       int thumbHeight = maxHeight;
       final double thumbRatio = (double) thumbWidth / (double) thumbHeight;
       final double photoRatio = (double) photoWidth / (double) photoHeight;

       if (thumbRatio < photoRatio)
           thumbHeight = (int) (thumbWidth / photoRatio);
       else
           thumbWidth = (int) (thumbHeight * photoRatio);

       // Checking if the photo's size is smaller than thumbnail's size: getting the original size
       if (photoWidth < thumbWidth) {
           thumbWidth = photoWidth;
       }
       if (photoHeight < thumbHeight) {
           thumbHeight = photoHeight;
       }

       final BufferedImage thumbnailBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       final Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbnailBufferedImage.createGraphics();

       // Best Quality Render Hints!
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
       graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);

       final AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
       t.scale((double) thumbWidth / photoWidth, (double) thumbHeight / photoHeight);

       graphics2D.setBackground(BKGROUND_COLOR);
       final boolean complete = graphics2D.drawImage(originalImage, t, this);

       if (!complete) {
           while (!imageLoaded) {
               try {
                   wait(100);
               } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               }
           }
       }

       graphics2D.dispose();

       return thumbnailBufferedImage;
   }

   private synchronized ByteArrayOutputStream makeThumbnail(final InputStream originalImageStream, final int maxWidth,
           final int maxHeight) throws Exception {

       SeekableStream seekableStream = SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(originalImageStream, true);
       RenderedOp reop = JAI.create("stream", seekableStream);
       Image photo = reop.getAsBufferedImage();

       final BufferedImage thumbnail = (BufferedImage) makeThumbnail(photo, maxWidth, maxHeight);

       final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ImageIO.write(thumbnail, GlobalResourceUtils.getFileExtension(), byteArrayStream);

       return byteArrayStream;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
       if (infoflags != ALLBITS) {
           // Image has not finished loading!
           // Return true to tell the image loading thread to keep drawing until image fully loads.
           return true;
       } else {
           imageLoaded = true;
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Hope this help :)